# Convert integer to equivalent number of blank spaces

Tags: java, string-formatting

I was wondering what the easiest way is to convert an integer to the equivalent number of blank spaces. I need it for the spaces between nodes when printing a binary search tree. I tried this

```
  int position = printNode.getPosition(); 
  String formatter = "%1"+position+"s%2$s\n";
  System.out.format(formatter, "", node.element);
```

But I am getting almost 3 times as many spaces compared to the int value of position. I'm not really sure if I am formatting the string right either.
Any suggestions would be great!
If it makes it clearer, say position = 6; I want 6 blank spaces printed before my node element.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you meant something like:

```
    int n = 6;
    String s = String.format("%1$"+n+"s", "");
```

---

```
System.out.format("[%13s]%n", "");  // prints "[             ]" (13 spaces)
System.out.format("[%1$3s]%n", ""); // prints "[   ]" (3 spaces)
```

Comment: +1. This answer is the simplest fix to OP's original problem: OP was just missing the `$` character.

Comment: In the "%1$"+n+"s", "", 
%1$ -> is the first argument.

So it would become : String.format("10s","");
How its printing 10 spaces.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 10):

You can create a `char[]` of the desired length, `Arrays.fill` it with spaces, and then create a `String` out of it (or just `append` to your own `StringBuilder` etc).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

int n = 6;
char[] spaces = new char[n];
Arrays.fill(spaces, ' ');
System.out.println(new String(spaces) + "!");
// prints "      !"
```

If you're doing this with a lot of possible values of `n`, instead of creating and filling `new char[n]` every time, you can create just one long enough string of spaces and take shorter `substring` as needed.

Comment: I think this will be faster than string buffer.

Answer (score 9):

This is an easy, but rubbish, way:

```
 int count = 20;
 String spaces = String.format("%"+count+"s", "");
```

or filled in

```
String spaces = String.format("%20s", "");
```

Answer (score 5):

Straight foward solution:

```
int count = 20;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(count);
for (int i=0; i < count; i++){
 sb.append(" ");
}
String s = sb.toString();
```

StringBuilder is efficient in terms of speed.

Comment: I should add "`String spaces = sb.toString();`"

Answer (score 3):

Why not loop over the integer and add a space on each iteration?

```
String spaces = "";
for (int i = 0 ; i < position ; i++) spaces += " ";
```

And you can use `StringBuilder` instead of String, if `position` might get very big and performance is an issue.

Comment: If you are going to do code like this, I would insist (if you where in my team) that you use a StringBuilder. Regardless of how many times you looped, using Strings like this is very inefficient and not recommended because the compiler will internally use StringBuilders to do the work anyway. But instead of doing it once, it will do it every loop. Also check out the Formatter class. It's doco talks about right justifying numbers using the width specification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
public class NestedLoop {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  int userNum  = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;


  while (i<=userNum) {
     System.out.println(i);
     ++i;
     if (i<=userNum) {
     for (j=0;j<i;j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");  
     }
    } 
   }
  return;
  }
}
```

If we make userNum = 3, the output would be:

```
0
 1
  2
   3
```

Hope it would help!

Answer (score 1):

If one were going to use an iterative solution anyway, one might want to do it a more "Groovy" way, like:

```
def spaces=6
print ((1..spaces).collect(" ").join())
```

Note that this doesn't work for zero spaces.  for that you might want something more like:

```
print (spaces?(1..spaces).collect(" ").join():"")
```

Answer (score 1):

//This prints the spaces according to the number in the variable n. So in this case it will print 15 spaces.

```java
int n=15;
System.out.format("%1$"+n+"s", "");
```